# Swiper JS slider with text content

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Can some one help me to develop a slider using swiper js or Gsap with the below design. I tried swiperjs and i am not able to have a dynamic slides.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy9e9.jpg

```
new Swiper(".news-events-slider", {
      speed: 800,
      slidesPerView: 4,
      centeredSlides: false,
      loop: true,
      grabCursor: false,
      slideToClickedSlide: true,
      slidesPerGroup: 1,
      spaceBetween: 50,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-btn-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-btn-prev",
      },
    });
```

Comment: That will be helpful https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/9swxhd